# input and select values returned on change by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select and an input that I would like the values to be returned by javascript anytime it is modified.  For example if I have a select with option "Yes" and "No", if the person selects "No" then I want that value to be returned in Javascript so I can make an action for it.

```
<select name="detailslot13">
<option selected="selected" value="N">No</option>
<option value="Y">Yes</option>
</select>
```

For now I'd just like the value be alerted in javascript.  Same thing with an input.

```
<input type="text" value="detailslot14" name="detailslot14" style="inherit !important;">
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you want with input? On every entered character, you want a js alert?

Comment: JavaScript newbie, right?

Comment: Selects have a fairly obvious change event that you can use. But with inputs you need to be clearer/more specific, as there are many logical events to hook into depending on the exact functionality you need.

Comment: @user1636946 As a good learner and contributor, if you found any answer useful, you should upvote for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    $('select[name="detailslot13"], input[name="detailslot14"]').change(function() {
        alert(this.value);
        // write your code
    });
  });
</script>
```

Input will show alert when user will be done with editing textfield and will click anywhere outside the textfield.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d5A25/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an eventlistener on your elements which notifies you when some values has changed:

```
var elems = ['detailslot13', 'detailslot14'],
    returnValueWhenChange = function(){
        alert(this.value);
    };

for(var i = 0, c = elems.length ; i < c ; i++){
    document.getElementById(elems[i]).addEventListener('change', returnValueWhenChange)
}
```

[**Here's an working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wXtK5/)

Comment: He wants to use jQuery, I believe.

Comment: oh ok right: $('#detailslot13, #detailslot14').on('change', function(e){ alert($(this).val()); }) should do

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/kumpF/)

You can use the following:

```
$(function() {
    $(':input').on('input', function() {
        alert( this.value );
    });
});
```